# parent controll in Codeigniter 2.2 project not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my CI 2.2 project I want to make my parent controll with app's common functionality for use in all app and for this I create file :
application/libraries/N_Controller.php :

```
<?php

class N_Controller extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

But on first attempt to use it in file 
application/controllers/admin/admin.php

```
<?php
class Admin extends N_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
```

I got  error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'N_Controller' not found in /controllers/admin/admin.php on line 3, referer: http://local-ci22.com/admin/hostel/edit/15
```

I tried to add in application/config/autoload.php file :

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array( 'AppSmarty', 'AppUtils', 'N_Controller');
```

But it did not help. Which is the correct way ?

Comment: Did you set up correct `$config['subclass_prefix']` in config/config.php ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extend the functionality of a system class. you need to follow this recomendations.

1. place your extended class in `/application/core`, be sure that you name it exactly like the name and casing of the class created.
2. your class should extend from `CI_Model` or `CI_Controller`, depending on your needs.
3. wherever you implement your new class, be sure that you honor the same name casing from your extended class.
4. you should have configured the `$config['subclass_prefix']` on `/application/config/config.php`. let's say in your case with the value `'N_'`

what i can see from your code, you are not extending from `CI_Controller` and your path seems wrong.

**Informative note**: the `/application/library` is used to place classes and libraries from 3rd parties that won't fit into CI schemas.